# Multi form cloned issue when submit. Submit first input group

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have a Script which load data from MySQL and then i generate a div for each result set. In each div i load several data and generate a form. The problem I have, is that the script is submitting the data from the first form.

Here the code:

```
   <script>
function getitems(){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'userAction.php',
        data: 'action_type=view&'+$("#userForm").serialize(),
        success:function(html){
            $('#userData').html(html);
        }
    });
}
function userAction(type,id){
    id = (typeof id == "undefined")?'':id;
    var statusArr = {add:"added",edit:"updated",delete:"deleted"};
    var userData = '';
    if (type == 'add') {
       userData = $("#addForm").find('#userForm'+id).serialize()+'&action_type='+type;
       }else{
        userData = 'action_type='+type+'&id='+id;
    }
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'userAction.php',
        data: userData,
        success:function(msg){
            if(msg == 'ok'){

                getitems();
                $('.form')[0].reset();

            }else{
                alert('Hubo un problema, intentar de nuevo!');
            }
        }
    });
}

</script>
```

And the form:

```
 <form class="form" id="userForm<?php echo $r['id']; ?>">
    <div class="form-group col-xs-7">
    <label>Descripcion</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="item_prt" id="item_prt"/>
       </div>
     <div class="form-group col-xs-3">
         <label>Precio</label>
   <input type="text" class="form-control" name="precio_prt" id="precio_prt"/>
   </div>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="idserv_prt" id="idserv_prt" value="<?php echo $orden;?>" />
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" id="addLink" onclick="userAction('add', '<?php echo $r['id']; ?>')"></a>
     </form>
```

I need to difference each form, because all are generated dinamically from mysql result. So, if I submit the first form, it works ok, but when I submit other one, It submit the first form too.

All works OK if i hace only one form.

Thanks!

Comment: With `$("#addForm").find('.form')` you are requesting data from the first form. You need to pass the form number or implement differently.

Comment: Edit your question with more explanation of what you are trying to achieve when you click the Add button.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the form ID as following :

```
...
if (type == 'add') {
   userData = $("#addForm").find('#userForm'+id).serialize()+'&action_type='+type;
   // ----------------------------------------^
}else{
   ...
```

and when you call the userAction() function just add the second parameter wish is the ID :

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" id="addLink" onclick="userAction('add', <?php echo $orden; ?>)"></a>
```

Comment: I did that, the forms has the ID added but still not work. It still looking the first form...

Comment: check if all the forms has different ID, and not the same ID

Comment: I update the post with the new code. All forms have different names and have the id correct.

Comment: in this case you shouldn't have `$("#userForm")` anymore !! within the `getitems()` function

Comment: getitems() is triggered when UserAction is done. Its not working and i have to figure out later. I need first to insert the form in the DB